# Ember data sending ids as strings when saving belongsTo

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, promise, rsvp-promise

I'm creating a cocktail app with the models "cocktail", "membership", and "ingredient". The cocktail and ingredient models are pretty self explanatory and the membership model is for objects that link a cocktail to an ingredient with amount.

```
App.Cocktail = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  created_by: DS.attr('number'),
  start_date: DS.attr('string'),
  end_date: DS.attr('string'),

  // link cocktail to memberships
  membership: DS.hasMany('membership',{ async: true })
});

App.Membership = DS.Model.extend({
  amount: DS.attr('string'),

  // link membership to ingredient and cocktail
  ingredient: DS.belongsTo('ingredient'),
  cocktail: DS.belongsTo('cocktail')
});

App.Ingredient = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  start_date: DS.attr('string'),
  end_date: DS.attr('string')
});
```

The problem I'm having is when I use ember-data to create a cocktail and then its memberships to ingredients the ingredient and cocktail ids for the REST call are strings not ints so the request body looks like this:

```
{membership:{amount:"2 litres",ingredient:"12",cocktail:"116"}}
```

when what I want instead:

```
{membership:{amount:"2 litres",ingredient:12,cocktail:116}}
```

Here's my code that performs the saving of which I'm pretty new to the idea of promises so not sure if this is structured in the most preferable way.

```
... code
  actions: {
    // fired when user presses save
    submit: function() {
      // some validation

      var cocktailPromise = this._saveCocktail();
      this._saveIngredientMemberships(cocktailPromise);
    }
  }
... more code
  _saveCocktail: function() {
    console.log('saving cocktail');

    var cocktail = this.store.createRecord('cocktail', {
      name: this.get('cocktailName'),
      description: this.get('cocktailDescription'),
      start_date: "now"
    });

    return cocktail.save();
  },

  _saveIngredientMemberships: function(cocktailPromise) {
    console.log('saving cocktail ingredients');

    // get the ingredients and amounts (memberships) the 
    // user entered and the store and set them as var here 
    // so they stay in scope.
    var memberships = this.get('memberships');
    var store = this.store;

    // once cocktail is created
    cocktailPromise.then(function(cocktail) {
      console.log('cocktail ready, saving ingredients');

      var membershipRecords = [];

      for( var i = 0 ; i < memberships.length ; i++ ) {
        membershipRecords[i] = store.createRecord('membership', {
          cocktail: cocktail,
          ingredient: memberships[i].get('ingredient'),
          amount: memberships[i].get('amount')
        });

        membershipRecords[i].save();
      }

    }, function() {
      console.log('something went wrong saving the cocktail!');
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Ember treats all IDs as strings (it coerces numbers to strings). What you'll want to do is override the `RESTSerializer`. You can find all of the possible methods to override [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html). I would advise that you read the [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js) for the adapter as well. That will really help. It's been a while since I've used Ember-Data, but I believe the method you want to look at is [serialize](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_serialize). I would do something like this:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    serialize: function(record, options) {
        var json = this._super(record, options);
        json.ingredient = parseInt(json.ingredient);
        json.cocktail = parseInt(json.cocktail);

        ...

        return json;
    }
});
```

You can obviously make it more efficient for different models, but you get the idea. You might also be able to override a more specific method, which is why I recommended reading the source code too.

Comment: Excellent thanks for this worked a treat and yes looking through the REST adapter source a bit more would certainly aid me :)